# Visual Studio 2017 Build Configuration Missing

Tags: visual-studio-2017, csproj

I have Visual Studio 2017 Community 15.7.2 installed. The build configuration drop down options disappear. I have been having Problems with the build configuration disappearing on my work machine (Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15.8.2) as well.

If I create a new project File -> New Project -> Web -> ASP.Net Web Application (.Net Framework).

The build configuration option shows up. Then if I click on a controller class e.g. HomeController.cs. The option clears out.

The option will show up again after changing "Show output from" under the Output window. If I bring up a .cs file again. The build option disappears:

[image: Build Configuration]

Is this now a normal behavior in Visual Studio? I suspect a bug in Visual Studio and have been updating more often than usual in attempt to fix it.

The latest update to Visual Studio Community 2017 (15.8.4) did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through each of the Tools -> Extensions and Updates and disable an extension and then restart Visual Studio. Start with ones that aren't created by Microsoft.

Repeat this until you have tried all the extensions.

Comment: Specifically this was the SelectNextOccurence extension. The bug was fixed here:
https://github.com/2mas/SelectNextOccurrence/pull/20